# generation of zero-inflated Poisson data in R

Tags: r, zero-inflation

I want to generate data from a zero-inflated Poisson distribution in R using the `mpath` package in the following way:

```
n <- 50
p <- 20
r <- 0.5    

# true parameter values 
beta <- numeric(p)  
beta[1] <- 1.8
beta[2] <- 0.5
beta[5] <- -0.3

gamma <- numeric(p)
gamma[1] <- 0.4
gamma[2] <- -0.5
gamma[3] <- 0.9

S <- matrix(0, nrow = p, ncol = p)
for(i in 1:p) {
  for(j in i:p) {
    S[i, j] <- r^(j - i)
    S[j, i] <- S[i, j]
  }
} 
X <- mvrnorm(n, rep(0, length(beta)), S)
Z <- mvrnorm(n, rep(0, length(gamma)), S)
bet0 <- matrix(beta, ncol = 1)
gama <- matrix(gamma, ncol = 1)
b <- (exp(Z %*% gama) / (1 + exp(Z %*% gama)))
a <- exp(X %*% bet0)
Y <- rzi(n, X, Z, a, b, family = "poisson", infl = TRUE)
```

but instead of getting the simulated data an error of the from `Error in x %*% a[-1] : non-conformable arguments` occur but I am unable to understand or solve it.

Comment: not sure what you are trying to do, but simulating from ZIP is so easy: just flip a coin with probability p, if heads then 0, if tails then simulate from Poisson(lambda)

Answer (score 1):

The question as, you asked it, is really a programming question and would have been more suitable for StackOverflow. But as it is worth to clarify some of the underlying ideas I'm answering it here with a little bit more context.

`rzi()` from `mpath` expects you to supply regressor matrices *without* intercept but expects that the first element of the coefficient vector is the intercept. (The documentation explains this incorrectly, though.) The intercept is then always included in the model and a logit link is always used for the zero-inflation probabilities.

Your code however had no intercepts at all. And it already computed the full vector of Poisson means $\lambda_i$ and zero-inflation probabilities $\pi_i$. From there it is easy to generate a zero-inflated Poisson variable from first principles rather than a supplied function where you struggled with the correct usage. Hence, I'll explain the latter here using somewhat simplified R code.

First, we fix the dimensions: `n` is the number of observations and `p` the number of "real" regressors excluding the intercept:

```
n <- 50
p <- 20
```

Then we set up the true coefficients including a zero intercept in both parts:

```
beta <- c(0, 1.8, 0.5, -0.3, rep(0, p - 3))
gamma <- c(0, 0.4, -0.5, 0.9, rep(0, p - 3))
```

The real regressors are multivariate normal with standard normal marginals and an AR(1) correlation structure $S_{i, j} = 0.5^{|i - j|}$.

```
corr <- matrix(0, nrow = 20, ncol = 20)
corr <- 0.5^abs(col(corr) - row(corr))
x <- MASS::mvrnorm(n, rep(0, p), corr)
z <- MASS::mvrnorm(n, rep(0, p), corr)
x <- cbind(1, x)
z <- cbind(1, z)
```

To compute the expectation $\log(\lambda_i) = x_i^\top \beta$ of the Poisson component a log-link is used (inverse: exp), and for the probabilitiy $\mathrm{logit}(\pi_i) = z_i^\top \gamma$ for zero-inflation a logit link is used (inverse: cumulative distribution function of the logistic distribution).

```
lambda <- exp(x %*% beta)
pi <- plogis(z %*% gamma)
```

Then with probability $\pi_i$ we observe a zero and with probability $1 - \pi_i$ we observe something from a Poisson($\lambda_i$) distribution. This can be compactly written using `rpois()` for the Poisson distribution multiplied with 0 vs. 1 from a Bernoulli distribution `rbinom(size = 1)`.

```
y <- rpois(n, lambda = lambda) * rbinom(n, prob = 1 - pi, size = 1)
```